# Time Series Decompose

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima

I'm new to the Time Series data analysis, and I have a data set which contains monthly revenue data.

```
+--------+--------+
|Column 1|Column 2|
+--------+--------+
|YYYY-mm |revenue |
+--------+--------+
```

And I tried to decompose in by using `seasonal_decompose()` in Python, and I got the results as below:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand why I can't observe any seasonal patterns after decomposing it. And why my trend plot looks similar to the original TS patterns.
As the next step I'll need to convert the TS data into *stationary* data in order to conduct the *ARIMA* model for prediction. Given my current decompose result, what should I do as the next step?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the relevant code and sample data that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.
I aggregated the data into quarterly then solve it. I guess it's because the data has too much noise at a month basis.

Comment: Can you plot out the figure again so we can understand what is the problem ?